# Issues with manual installation of predictionIO dependencies

Tags: elasticsearch, installation, hbase, apache-spark, predictionio

I am installing predictionIO from source code. I have downloaded and done the predictionIO installation successfully. I am now trying to install the dependencies (Spark, Elasticsearch, HBase) but I am running into errors for each of them. Below are the issues I am facing when I execute pio status:
1 - Unable to locate a proper Apache Spark installation
2 - It is also unable to find metadata files.

I have not changed any default settings. I'm using windows 8.1. On localhost, I have running IIS. On 127.0.0.1:8888 I run ipython notebook.

Please help on how I can get predictionIO up and running on my machine. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the relevant thread.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/predictionio-user/SAS/predictionio-user/0awaASUR8lE/JkLtPeRrNt4J

Moreover, PredictionIO docs had a few errors. Below are some of them and their corrected versions.

1 - Actual line: PATH=$PATH:/home/yourname/predictionio/bin; export PATH

Corrected Version PATH=$PATH:/home/yourname/PredictionIO/bin; export PATH

2 - Actual Line: $ pio eventserver

Corrected Version: $ pio eventserver --ip 0.0.0.0

3 - Actual Line pio template get PredictionIO/templates-scala-parallel-recommendation MyRecommendation

Corrected Version pio template get PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-recommendation MyRecommendation

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, you can install with Vagrant.

http://docs.prediction.io/community/projects/#vagrant-installation-for-predictionio

Comment: Yes I have done that already, but I wanted to know why its not working on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the discussion has moved to the google group.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/predictionio-user/SAS/predictionio-user/ZamBr1ZaQ3o/fyNkXh3zsv0J

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/predictionio-user/SAS/predictionio-user/0awaASUR8lE/JkLtPeRrNt4J